# Adding triples in a certain order using RDFLib Python

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib, turtle-rdf, triples

I am looking to add triples in a certain order using Python's RDFLib Library. I'm aware RDF triples have no ordering, however, I was hoping to add the triples in the order in which the add() function is called. For example,

If I add the following triples

```
bob = URIRef("http://example.org/people/Bob")
name = Literal("Bob")

g.add((bob, RDF.type, FOAF.Person))
g.add((bob, FOAF.name, name))
```

The output generated

```
ex:Bob foaf:name "Bob"; 
       rdf:type foaf:Person.
```

Would there be a way to ensure the order in which the add function is called correlates with the output file? E.g

```
ex:Bob rdf:type foaf:Person.
       foaf:name "Bob".
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: no, that's not possible, but you can simply extend/write the Turtle or N-Triples serializer - I mean, the code is open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. From the [documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gettingstarted.html),

> RDFLib graphs are un-sorted containers; they have ordinary set operations (e.g. add() to add a triple) plus methods that search triples and return them in arbitrary order.